# Optimize the trigger to add audit log

Tags: postgresql

I have a local database which is the production database, on which all operations are being done real time. I am storing the log on each action in an audit log table in another database via trigger. It basically checks if any change is made in any of the row's column it will remove that row and add it AGAIN (which is not a good way I think as it should simply update it but due to some reasons I need to delete and add it again).

There are some tables on which operations are being done rapidly like `100s` of rows are being added in database. This is slowing the process of saving the data into audit log table. Now if trigger has to like delete `100` `rows` and add `100` again it will affect the performance obviously and if number of rows increases it will reduce the performance more.

What should be the best practice to tackle this, I have been looking into `Read Replica` and `Foreign Data Wrapper` but as for Read Replica it's only Readable and not writable for PostgreSQL and I don't really get to know how Foreign Data Wrapper gonna help me as this was suggested by one of my colleague.

Hope someone can guide me in right direction.

Comment: "*it will remove that row and add it AGAIN*" - what exactly is it doing, can  you show the code of the trigger function please? It's unclear why you are doing this, or why you would want to *update* an audit log at all. Or why you would want a writable replica. Can you tell use more about your use case?

Answer (score 1):

A **log** is **append-only** by definition. Loggers should never be modifying or removing existing entries.

Audit logs are no different. Audit triggers should `INSERT` an entry for each change (however you want to define "change"). They should never `UPDATE` or `DELETE` anything*.

The change and the corresponding log entry should be written to the same database within the same transaction, to ensure atomicity/consistency; logging directly to a remote database will always leave you with a window where the log is committed but the change is not (or vice versa).

If you need to aggregate these log entries and push them to a different database, you should do it from an external process, not within the trigger itself. If you need this to happen in real time, you can inform the process of new changes via a [notification channel](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html).

---

* In fact, you should [revoke](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-revoke.html) `UPDATE`/`DELETE` privileges on the audit table from the user inserting the logs. Furthermore, the trigger should ideally be a `SECURITY DEFINER` function owned by a privileged user with `INSERT` rights on the log table. The user connecting to the database should not be given permission to write to the log table directly.

This ensures that if your client application is compromised (whether due to a malfunction, or a malicious user e.g. exploiting an SQL injection vulnerability), then your audit log retains a complete and accurate record of everything it changed.